# Exec format error windows bash

Tags: windows, bash, executable

I'm currently working on the new native ubuntu Bash on Windows, and I cannot execute .exe files like java or sublime text3, the error message is:

> bash: /mnt/c/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/sublime_text.exe : cannot
>   execute binary file : exec() format error

Comment: /mnt/c/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/java.exe: PE32+ executable (console) x86-64, for MS Windows

Comment: here there is a similar question: https://superuser.com/questions/1122188/running-win32-program-from-bash-for-windows-10